# Where do void function/property calls execute to?

Tags: java, kotlin, compilation

Here's code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    val items = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
    items.first() 
    items.last() 
    items.filter { it % 2 == 0 }  
}
```

I have some extension methods like `first()` and `last()` - but they arn't doing anything (not being a assigned to a variable of anything). Does this mean the compiler just skips over them and doesn't do anything?

Answer (score 2):

> but they arn't doing anything (not being a assigned to a variable of anything)

So far as the compiler knows, they could have side-effects (e.g. printing something or setting a field) and in this case they'd have to be executed. If they were [`inline`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html), the compiler could maybe eliminate them as Josh's answer mentions, after inlining. But they aren't, so the compiler can't rely on their *definitions* (as opposed to signatures): at the runtime there could be a different JAR containing these methods and defining them with side effects.

But JIT will very likely inline them and then eliminate if you run this code enough time; just not immediately.

In principle there could be [contracts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html) declaring these methods to be pure and then the compiler could eliminate them. But current contracts don't support this, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

The methods get called because you invoked it, but the results you didn't store in a reference variable, it would still be created on the heap if I'm not wrong (immediately eligible for garbage collection) but without a variable reference linked to it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is called dead code elimination. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756462/java-dead-code-elimination) is one related post that addresses a similar question.